# What does one-dimension mean for thermal conductivity?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I am starting to learn the Fourier's law, but I am getting confused with [the following sentence on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_conduction#Integral_form:%7E:text=The%20above%20differential%20equation%2C%20when%20integrated%20for%20a%20homogeneous%20material%20of%201%2DD%20geometry%20between%20two%20endpoints%20at%20constant%20temperature%2C%20gives%20the%20heat%20flow%20rate%20as):

> The above differential equation, when integrated for a homogeneous material of 1-D geometry between two endpoints at constant temperature, gives the heat flow rate as:

I am wondering what "1-D geometry" means (isn't all the thing we deal with 3D geometry?) and curious what we could use this formula for (which shape?):

$$\frac{Q}{\Delta t} = -kA\frac{\Delta T}{\Delta x}$$

Also, could I use this formula for determining the heat transfer for a bottle that looks something like this?

[image]

If not, what should be the equation I use for the heat transfer for that bottle? I tried to search for the three dimensional form of Fourier's law, but found limited results and no useful information.

Answer (score 5):

*One dimension* here means that the problem is homogeneous in the dimensions perpendicular to the dimension of interest. This means that the equations to be analyzed depend only on one variable, i.e., they are *one-dimensional* equations.

This is different from *one-dimensional* as understood, e.g., when applied to a thin rod, or a pipe (or one-dimensional structures on nanoscale, such as *quantum wires*) - where we would be talking about a system that is *physically* one-dimensional, in the sense that its length is much bigger than its width (transversal size.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. So here the one dimension just mean change one variable in the equation, is that correct? Sorry as a non native English speaker the language is a little bit complex for me

Comment: Actually, I am doing an experiment to see how the change in the thickness of the bottle will affect the time it cools down. For this experiment, do you think I could use the above equation as my theoretical result? Thank you!

Comment: @James we mean that derivatives in the other directions are zero. E.g., the heat flux is $\mathbf{q}=-k\nabla T$, but $\partial_yT=\partial_zT=0$, so that $q_y,=q_z=0$.

Comment: If the bottle is sufficiently wide, you probably could still use this result, but your coefficient will depend on the cross-sectional area (btw, what is $A$ in your equation?)

Comment: Thank you so much. The a is the inner surface area and the bottle will be about 100 ml volume. To be honest I am writing a report for my experiment and I am concerned if my supported equation is wrong.

Comment: Sorry, to confirm, the one dimension just mean the heat all one from one direction, is it correct. Sorry and thank you soooo much!

Comment: Sorry just wonder could I still use the equation in my case?

Comment: @James if you think about it: a small piece of a cylinder is almost exactly like a cube. So you may choose to calculate it like that - as long as the thickness of the cylinder is a lot smaller than its radius.

Comment: @user253751, thank you very much, the thickness is of course much smaller than the radius, what I am keeping struggling with is how I make it being reasonable in my report. In my assumption, the one dimension will go from one side to another side (just like the wall), but for my case, it is like the inner heat go outside from the cylinder to any side, do you think (if this is cube), I could use this equation? Thanks

Comment: @James yes, from inside to outside. You're pretending the cylinder is unrolled to make a flat sheet. As long as the radius is much bigger than the thickness, this is a reasonable approximation. In physics, approximations are used all the time to make calculations simple. If the cylinder was very thick to its radius, this wouldn't be a good idea, because a thick cylinder has more area on one side than the other. But a thin cylinder has almost the same area, just like a sheet.

Comment: @user253751 Sorry, last question, so the idea that if we the cylinder is too thick will be bad is because in this case, the outer surface will much bigger than the inner surface area, so we can't pretend it is unrolled to several flat sheet, otherwise, our data will be much off, is this correct?  thank you sooooo much. You are really a life saver!!!

Comment: @James yeah.... Also you are ignoring the top and bottom, and pretending the sheet goes on forever with no edge. Again, this is a reasonable approximation, if most of the cylinder isn't edge.

Comment: @user253751 Thank you very much. It solves all my confusion!!! Save me from hours of research. btw, if you want, you could post this as answer, so I can accept it

Comment: @James hmm, I'm not sure I can do that without copying Roger Vadim's notes about what one-dimensional means

Comment: @user253751, anyways, thank you very very much

Answer (score 4):

> what does "1 D geometry" means (isn't all the thing we deal with 3D geometry?)

Yes, our world is 3D. But if you had a very long item, insulated along the sides, the temperature variation throughout the cross-section might be minimal and uninteresting compared to the temperature variation along the length. Thus, you might model the heat flux as $q=-k\frac{dT}{dx}$ for simplicity.

More generally, you’d model the heat flux as $q=-k\nabla T$, the 3D version.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  So the 3D version seems to be the same from the 1D gemoetry, but the 3D version one has not be simpified (is that right)? In this case, should I use 3D version or 1D for the bottle

Comment: The picture above shows rotational symmetry, so you could operate in [cylindrical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula) and consider only the radial direction. Any introductory heat transfer book (e.g., Incropera & DeWitt) will discuss how to do this.

Comment: Sorry I am getting a little bit confused here. What does the cylindrical coordinates related to the equation we are talking about and how could I embed it into Fourier's law? Thank you

Comment: In the [heat equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_equation), the Laplacian is different in cylindrical coordinates. The heat equation is what one solves to obtain a temperature distribution, given the boundary and initial conditions. Ignore this if it's not relevant.

Comment: For rotational symmetry, we have $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right)+\frac{\partial^2T}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{\alpha}\dot{T}$, where $r$ and $z$ are respectively the radial and vertical distances, $T$ is the temperature, and $\alpha$ is the thermal diffusivity. Again, an introductory heat transfer book will be a useful resource.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to find the equation that works in my case. I probably will go to find a introductory heat transfer book, but it is clear in my case that I can't use one dimension version, is this right?

Comment: If you ignore vertical heat transfer, the heat equation becomes the one-dimensional $\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r\frac{\partial T}{\partial r}\right)=\frac{1}{\alpha}\dot{T}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I don't want to waste your time but if you have, do you know the name of this formula or any reference for that I could take a look? The ∂ and vertical distance confuses me. Sorry

Comment: It is the heat equation with a cylindrical Laplacian, as described by the Wikipedia links in this comment chain.